# Calculate the average cumulative distribution

Tags: distributions, matlab, mean

I'm looking at some reaction time data for many individuals.  So, for example, one individual will have several hundred measurements in the range of [-200 1000] for the reaction time to a stimulus presentation and I have N such individuals.

I like to plot cumulative distributions to get a qualitative picture of this data.  I have no problem doing that for the individuals (using Matlab currently), but I'm uncertain how to plot the average cumulative distribution for the group.

Assuming I have N individual cumulative distributions, defined over [-200 1000], how do I go about averaging these appropriately?  My first instinct is to just use:

Z(z) = (X1(z) + X2(z) + X3(z) ... XN(z)) / N, z = [-200 1000]

That is, average each distribution value at a given z in the range [-200 1000].  This does seem to give a good picture of the group dynamic, and allow me to compare different groups of individuals, but is it strictly correct?